# Copy File from local server to Web server using PHP with FTP connection

Tags: php, curl

I want to copy a file to my server from local drive.

But Error:

```
    Warning: ftp_login(): Sorry, cleartext sessions are not accepted on this server. 
    in D:\xampp\htdocs\shilpa\national\upload_file.php on line 9
```

not done

Comment: So of course you googled "Sorry, cleartext sessions are not accepted on this server." and got this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371947/421-sorry-cleartext-sessions-are-not-accepted-on-this-server right?

Comment: What (if any) client are you using (ex. FileZilla)?

Answer (score 0):

It means that your server only allows SFTP.

Source: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-w3-total-cache-want-to-try-self-hosted-cdn-on-shared-network-problems

Comment: He isn't taking about WP.