# Error uploading images to server using ftp and php script, giving error on ftp_put() login

Tags: php, ftp, cpanel

I have a script written in php which basically uploads images to a server.
I'm uploading this script onto my server using an ftp account credentials. However when I try to access it, it gives me login error. Here's the error log:

> [09-Apr-2014 19:00:01 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  ftp_login(): Sorry,
>   cleartext sessions are not accepted on this server. in
>   /home/gameeon/public_html/jts/local_upload.php on line 8 [09-Apr-2014
>   19:01:33 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  ftp_login(): Sorry, cleartext
>   sessions are not accepted on this server. in
>   /home/gameeon/public_html/jts/local_upload.php on line 8 [09-Apr-2014
>   19:01:55 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  ftp_login(): Sorry, cleartext
>   sessions are not accepted on this server. in
>   /home/gameeon/public_html/jts/local_upload.php on line 8 [09-Apr-2014
>   19:02:21 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  ftp_login(): Sorry, cleartext
>   sessions are not accepted on this server. in
>   /home/gameeon/public_html/jts/local_upload.php on line 8 [09-Apr-2014
>   19:03:59 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  ftp_login(): Sorry, cleartext
>   sessions are not accepted on this server. in
>   /home/gameeon/public_html/jts/local_upload.php on line 8

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "ftp.gameeon.in"; // enter the ftp host name
$ftp_username = "temp@gameeon.in"; // put your ftp user name
$ftp_userpass = "********"; // put your ftp password

$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

/// put the path of your image folder in your remote server i.e:
$ftp_upload_path="public_html/img/";

/// put the path of your image folder in your local machine:
$files = glob("E:/upload_images/*.*");

 foreach($files as $fl)
 {

     $fl_arr = explode("/",$fl); 
     $cn=count($fl_arr);
     $num=$cn-1;
     $file=$fl_arr[$num];

     // upload file
     // $fl = full path of localimages

     if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $ftp_upload_path.$file,$fl, FTP_ASCII))
     {
         echo "Successfully uploaded $file. <br/>";
     }
     else
     {
         echo "Error uploading $file.<br/>";
     }
     sleep(3); /// pausing the code for 3 secs before next upload

 }

 // close connection
 ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

I'm getting an error on this line no. 8 which is:

```
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [421 Sorry, cleartext sessions are not accepted on this server.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371947/421-sorry-cleartext-sessions-are-not-accepted-on-this-server)

Comment: Tried it, not working.

Comment: Still the same error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`ftp_ssl_connect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php) function instead of `ftp_connect()` because server is using **Explicit TLS/SSL**

Try this:

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server)
            or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
```

If you are working on `localhost` you may encounter error saying

> ftp_put(): I won't open a connection to 192.**.**.* something..

Then you have to use the [`ftp_pasv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php) function.

As of docs:

> In passive mode, data connections are initiated by the client, rather
>   than by the server. It may be needed if the client is behind firewall.

In your case yes you need to use it you are using **Explicit TLS/SSL** just before your loop add this:

```
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);
```

Also set your path `public_html/img/` to `/img/` or whatever directory exists:

```
$ftp_upload_path = "/img/";
```

Comment: This solved the login connection problem but now I am not able to upload images :(

The script just doesn't upload the images on server and there's no error log message as well!

Comment: Where are you working with this script in your remote host or localhost? If remote host your images path will not work because it will check them on remote server. Also make sure your FTP access has `/public_html/img` folder

Comment: Oh, alright the code is working just fine with the remote server, however I want the code to fetch images from my 'upload_images' folder on my 'E' drive as mentioned in the folder. I am getting a number of images getting uploaded on the server but not the ones to which I have provided the path to on my PC.

Comment: Alright, give me 10 minutes, testing it out. And thanks for all the help btw.