# Extension installer error in OpenCart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.3

I tried to upload file in extension installer in opencart 2.3.0.2 but I get error message:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data
>
> OK
>
> **Warning**: ftp_login(): Sorry, cleartext sessions are not
>   accepted on this server. in
>   **/***/***/***/*/*/***/admin/controller/extension/installer.php**
>   on line **294**{"error":"Could not login as admin"}

Please find the attached below screenshot

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your error to your post (not as a image.)

Comment: @DigitCart i edited my Post can You please give me the solution now?

Comment: Are you sure about your OC version? It seems that you are using 2.3.0.2

Comment: yeah its 2.3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

> You need to use ftp_ssl_connect() function instead of ftp_connect()
>   because server is using Explicit TLS/SSL

Try this:

```
admin\controller\extension\installer.php
```

**Find:**

```
$connection = ftp_connect($this->config->get('config_ftp_hostname'), $this->config->get('config_ftp_port'));
```

**Change to:**

```
$connection = ftp_ssl_connect($this->config->get('config_ftp_hostname'), $this->config->get('config_ftp_port'));
```

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22969260/4330223

https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=142341#p585561