# login to FTP (pure-ftpd) server causing problems

Tags: networking

ftp server running `pure-ftpd` is causing me problems logging in.  Whenever I try to log in using a valid username and password, it says to try using SSL/TLS mechanism.

Comment: Which FTP client are you using?  Filezilla?

Comment: core ftp lite on windows 7

Comment: Off-topic, http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you adjusted the SSL auth settings?  https://support.winhost.com/kb/a672/how-to-set-up-coreftp-to-use-ftp-over-ssl.aspx, specifically items 12 through 15.

```
12. In the "Connection" dropdown box, select "AUTH SSL".
13. Under "SSL Options", check "SSL Listings" and "SSL Transfer". Leave "Clear (CCC)" unchecked.
14. Check "Windows SSL".
15. Click "Connect". A box will pop up labeled "Certificate Information". Click "Always Accept".
```

Comment: i am getting an error response back "sorry clear text session are not accepted on this server"

Comment: Have you tried these suggestions?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371947/421-sorry-cleartext-sessions-are-not-accepted-on-this-server

Comment: how do clients generally connect to a ftp server configured like this is it just the username and password that you require or you need something extra like a public  key for authentication.