# Curl(28): Timeout was reached

Tags: curl, github, travis-ci

On attempting to upload some files to my web server using this script

```
#!/bin/bash
gitLastCommit=$(git show --summary --grep="Merge pull request")
 if [[ -z "$gitLastCommit" ]]
 then
    lastCommit=$(git log --format="%H" -n 1)
else
    echo "We got a Merge Request!"
      arr=($gitLastCommit)
      lastCommit=${arr[4]}
  fi
echo $lastCommit

filesChanged=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $lastCommit)
  if [ ${#filesChanged[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "No files to update"
 else
    for f in $filesChanged
    do
        #do not upload these files that aren't necessary to the site
        if [ "$f" != ".travis.yml" ] && [ "$f" != "deploy.sh" ]
        then
            echo "Uploading $f"
            curl --ftp-create-dirs -T $f -u $FTP_USER:$FTP_PASS 
ftp://$FTP_ADDRESS/var/www/test/$f
        fi
    done
fi
```

It all works well until the curl line runs and then I get this error `curl: (28) Timeout was reached` after this in my log:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

The variables `FTP_USER`, `FTP_PASSWORD` and `FTP_ADDRESS` are all assigned in my .travis.yml file

```
language: generic

notifications:
  email: false

env:
  global:
  - secure: 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
  - secure: 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
  - secure: 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

before_install:
  - chmod +x deploy.sh

after_success:
    ./deploy.sh
```

UPDATE: Adding -v to the curl command gives this output

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying [secure]...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to [secure] ([secure]) port 21 (#0)
< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
< 220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
< 220-Local time is now 10:33. Server port: 21.
< 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
> USER [secure]
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     
0< 421 Sorry, cleartext sessions are not accepted on this server.
* We got a 421 - timeout!
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Timeout was reached
```

Comment: FTP server is rejecting your plain text connection via `curl` and waiting for further input. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11371947/136333

Comment: @banzaiman, if I try to use ftps or ftpes they both don't work